# Why am I not able to use relative path to open a file in CLion?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clion

I seem to get errors when trying to open an `std::ifstream` if I use a relative path. Though it works fine if using an absolute path.

Is there something I need to add to the CMakeLists.txt? (I'm pretty new to using cmake) Or is it just a problem in CLion?

Comment: Have you checked your working directory? It might be started in a different directory than you expect.

Comment: Ah, that was the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's CLion. You have to set the Working Directory in your compilation options. (under run > edit configurations)
For example:
[image: Settings Screenshot]

Because CLion works in an other directory on ubuntu under `~/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/[id_of_project]`